# What are analogs for classes from *autoconfigure.security.oauth2 and *security.oauth2 for Spring Boot 2.1.1.RELEASE?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

What are analogs for classes from *autoconfigure.security.oauth2 and *security.oauth2 for Spring Boot 2.1.1.RELEASE version of spring-boot-starter-parent?

They are removed in this version.

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.UserInfoTokenServices;

import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientContext;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableOAuth2Client;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're missing is a dependency on `spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure` to make your old setup work "seamlessly" with Spring Boot 2.1.1.RELEASE

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

That being said that project is maintenance mode and the recommended approach is to use the [built in Spring Oauth support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2client).